# Ms Access form control calculate value based on time of day

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a combo box [cboShift] that has two selections "Daylight" and "Afternoon". I want to auto select the shift based on the current time.

So if the current time is from 2:01am to 4pm then I need the combobox selection to be daylight and if its 4:01pm to 2am its selection would be afternoon.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it how to find out what time it is? Or is it how to set the selected item in the combobox? You forgot to ask a question. Please [edit] your post to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were tring to do?

```
Function getShift() As String
Dim tm As Date
Dim evstart As Date
Dim evend As Date
Dim retval As String
tm = Format(Now(), "hh AMPM")
evstart = "4:00pm"
evend = "2:00am"
If (tm <= evstart) Then
    If (tm >= evend) Then
        retval = "Daylight"
    Else
    retval = "Afternoon"
    End If
End If
getShift = retval
End Function
```

[image: Here is how you set Default]
It will only show up when you move to a new record on the form.

Comment: Yes it looks like what im looking for but how can I call from the controls default value? I tried to enter =getShift() and it does nothing its still just an empty space waiting for me to click on it to select daylight or afternoon. Thanks!

Comment: for the default value of the form =getShift() should work fine. Just make sure you declare getShift inside one of your public modules not the backend of the form.

Comment: Benaiah, yes I tried that prior and its not working for me. I go to new record and its still blank. The only way that worked was HansUp value list way..... Thanks!